# ABP Migration 3.3 to 4.2 Angular Breaking changes and Deprecate the ConfigState

Tags: angular, abp

**After upgrading from 3.3 to 4.2 and upgrading Angular to 11, I'm getting the following error:**

````
    ```core.js:6157 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'language')
        at abp-ng.core.js:1374
        at Store.selectSnapshot (ngxs-store.js:3179)
        at LocalizationService.get currentLang [as currentLang] (abp-ng.core.js:1374)
        at LazyStyleHandler.listenToLanguageChanges (abp-ng.theme.shared.js:2799)
        at new LazyStyleHandler (abp-ng.theme.shared.js:2770)
        at Array. (abp-ng.theme.shared.js:2849)
        at ApplicationInitStatus.runInitializers (core.js:27827)
        at core.js:29152
        at _callAndReportToErrorHandler (core.js:29254)

    main.ts:13 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'language')
        at abp-ng.core.js:1374
        at Store.selectSnapshot (ngxs-store.js:3179)
        at LocalizationService.get currentLang [as currentLang] (abp-ng.core.js:1374)
        at LazyStyleHandler.listenToLanguageChanges (abp-ng.theme.shared.js:2799)
        at new LazyStyleHandler (abp-ng.theme.shared.js:2770)
        at Array. (abp-ng.theme.shared.js:2849)
        at ApplicationInitStatus.runInitializers (core.js:27827)
        at core.js:29152
        at _callAndReportToErrorHandler (core.js:29254)
        at core.js:29150 ```
````

I followed this guide https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Migration-Guides/Abp-4_0-Angular
and I have a replaced the layout.

I suspect my problem has to do with the deprecated the ConfigState

Comment: Did you import `NgxsModule.forRoot()` in your `app.module`?

Comment: I yes I had, turned out to be the package versions in my package.json